# string::assign doesn't work in vector of strings

Tags: c++

Why this program crashes? It crashes on line `vec[0].assign("blabla");`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     vector<string> vec;
     vec.reserve(5);
     vec[0].assign("blabla");
}
```

Or this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.reserve(5);
    vec[0].push_back('a');
}
```

And what is best to use instead of if it really doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
vec[0].assign("blabla");
```

This causes undefined behavior. `vec[0]` has been reserved but not allocated. You should use push or emplace instead.

---

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
vec[0].push_back('a');
```

Same error. You are pushing to `vec[0]` which is not exist in memory yet.

---

**Solution:**

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.reserve(5);
vec.emplace_back("blabla"); //or push_back
```

Or:

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.resize(5);// Notice resize not reserve
vec[0].assign("blabla");//this works now since vec[0] is exist
```

Or:

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.resize(5);// Notice resize not reserve
vec[0].push_back('b'); //this works now since vec[0] is exist
```

I do **NOT** prefer the second option since it causes construction N times then assignment N times